# Filtering a string from email body with Python

Tags: python, regex, email

I am attempting to filter out only the text in the body of the email message using Python.
I need to get that "Needed Content" part of the mail.
Here's a string that I get when receiving a mail:

```
'--001a1144b8cc8e9a67055ddfb9ec
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Needed Content

--001a1144b8cc8e9a67055ddfb9ec
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr">Off</div>

--001a1144b8cc8e9a67055ddfb9ec--
'
```

I have tried something like that but failed:

```
re.findall(r'/\r/\n(.+?)/\r/\n', body)
```

To filter out between the line breaks but failed..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`^(--\S+)\s*^Content-Type:.*\s*([\s\S]*?(?=\s*\1))` capture group 2](https://regex101.com/r/qY6Rje/1). Not exactly sure what is and is not consistent, so I'm assuming those two parts are consistent (`--\S+` and `Content-Type:`). Assuming you only need the `Needed Content` you can edit above and add `\s*text/plain;` after `Content-Type:`

Comment: Neither is working for me,..
word1 =  re.findall(r'^(--\S+)\s*^Content-Type:.*\s*([\s\S]*?(?=\s*\1))', body)
word2 = re.findall(r'text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n\n(.+)\n\n\-\-', body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match `\r\n`, just use `[\r\n]` like so:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=[\r\n]).+(?=[\r\n])', body)
```

But python re.findall has a flag to treat each line separately, which makes your code easier to read:

```
re.findall(r'^.+$', body, re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead assertion([?=](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)).

```
>>> import re
>>> body='--001a1144b8cc8e9a67055ddfb9ec\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8' 
>>> re.findall(".+(?=\nContent-Type)",body)                                   ['--001a1144b8cc8e9a67055ddfb9ec']
```